# Efficiently mapping a number between two bases given a particular condition on the digits

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle, computational-mathematics

I am currently faced with the following problem.
Suppose I have a number $N$ in base $a$, and let $N_0, N_1, \cdots, N_n$ be the digits of said number in that base. It is also given that $N_i < b \space \forall \space i$. I want to build the number $M$ in base $b$, such as $N_i = M_i \space \forall \space i$. Of course, I can compute $M$ as $M = \sum_{i} N_i b^i$.
My question is: can we do any better, computationally? Especially given that we know $n$, the number of digits in both bases, is there any trick we can use to do this more efficiently?
I am especially interested in any solution that doesn't involve "unpacking" the digits of $N$ (that is, computing the values of $N_i$). This is because i will be implementing this conversion in computer program that heavily relies on this, and the modulo operation is generally rather slow (compared to sums, multiplications or bitwise binary operators).
Thank you for your time, and forgive me if I wasn't clear at any point!

(also forgive me if the tags may not be appropriate, but I don't really know how to tag this question)

Comment: No. When you exclude numbers with base-$a$ expansions containing certain digits, you have to realize that between any two numbers where the function is defined, there are infinitely many places where it is not. But the function maps this broken domain bijectively onto the entire real numbers, which means it has a highly discontinuous inverse. The operations built into computers are continuous in nature (though the computer itself can only handle a discrete domain). So they cannot handle that discontinuity easily. You are not going to find any easy solution here.

Comment: I should correct that the function is only *almost* bjective. There are a countable number of cases of two input values giving the same output value. So one has to remove a countable number of entries from the domain to get a function iwith a full inverse. But in any case, my main point still holds. The sort of operations that are *easily* carried out by computer have well-behaved local inverses, and so cannot represent this function.